# I don't know my info

Tags: support, user-accounts, account-recovery

I signed up for stack exchange about a year and a half ago, and have it signed in on my phone and can (clearly) ask questions. I want to sign in on my laptop, but it keeps saying that there is no account under any of my e-mail addresses, and none of the external sign ins are associated with my account. Is there any way I can get into my account, or an I just going to have to start over?

Comment: Can you follow the [steps to add credentials](/help/edit-credentials) on your phone?

Comment: I try to follow the link, and the app crashes.

Comment: You signed in with Google, not an email/password combo, if that helps.